# Highcharts: collecting all charts on a page second time produces error

Tags: highcharts

I have a puzzling situation.

I have a page with a few column charts. On this page, there is also a link, clicking on which builds a form and sends data to server, which sends back a PDF document:

```
$('#my-link").click(function(ev) {

        var svgArray=[];
        $(Highcharts.charts).each(function(i, chart){    
            svgArray.push(chart.getSVG()); <!--show error "TypeError: chart is undefined" in Firefox when clicking on it the second time without refreshing the page -->
        });
        var svgJson = JSON.stringify(svgArray); 
        var form = $('#my-form');
        var ele = $('<input name="chartSvgArray" style="display: none" value="' +         $.base64('encode', svgJson) + '">');
        form.append(ele);
        form.submit();

        ev.preventDefault();
});
```

The browser is able to get the PDF document (with charts in it) from the server and to prompts me for opening it or saving it. In the above I uses two Javascript tools. JSON and .base64 http://www.jqueryscript.net/text/Base64-Decode-Encode-Plugin-base64-js.html.

Here is where I have a problem. Without refreshing the page, I click the link again, I get the error in this line:

```
svgArray.push(chart.getSVG()); <!--show error "TypeError: chart is undefined" in Firefox when clicking on it the second time without refreshing the page -->
```

If I refresh (reload) the page, there is no problem for producing the document each time.

Can anybody show me how to fix this?

Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that in `Highcharts.chart` array you have all charts created and destroyed. When you call `getSVG()` new chart (duplicate) is created and will be available in that array. Now, once chart is removed, it's replaced with `undefined`, so result after exporting first time may be:

```
Highcharts.charts[] = [ chart1, chart2, undefined, undefined ];
```

**Solution** is simple, just check if `chart` variable exists:

```
$(Highcharts.charts).each(function(i, chart){   
    if(chart) svgArray.push(chart.getSVG()); 
});
```

Comment: Pawel, thanks for your input! You mean that in the second export I can still collect all charts but need to use that "if test" to skip undefined? Are the newly created charts in Highcharts.chart placed in the order they show up on the page? Thanks!!!

Comment: Yes, the order in that array is the same as they are created on the page. And yes, you need to use `if(chart) ... ` to make sure you won't try to exporting non-exporting chart. Or instead of `if(chart)` you can use `if(typeof chart === 'undefined')`. Second one should be more safe.